# How to call Parent function with useState Hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

The ideal result is displaying strings when items in the list are clicked.

Here's the Root Component.

```
const App = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(null);
  const handleClick = name => {
    setClick(name);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent handleClick={handleClick} />
      {click && <p>{click} is clicked.</p>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and Parent Component.

```
const Parent = ({ handleClick }) => (
  <div>
    <Child
      name="First Item"
      handleClick={handleClick("First Item is Clicked!")}
    />
    <Child
      name="Second Item"
      handleClick={handleClick("Second Item is Clicked!")}
    />
    <Child
      name="Third Item"
      handleClick={handleClick("Third Item is Clicked!")}
    />
  </div>
);
```

and Child Component.

```
const Child = ({ name, handleClick }) => <li onClick={handleClick}>{name}</li>;
```

Also, the code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-template-mmzox?fontsize=14).

I just wondered why the result never is never changed by click.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is that you aren't passing a function to `handleClick` instead an evaluated value from parent. You code must be

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = ({ handleClick }) => (
  <div>
    <Child
      name="First Item"
      handleClick={() => handleClick("First Item is Clicked!")}
    />
    <Child
      name="Second Item"
      handleClick={() => handleClick("Second Item is Clicked!")}
    />
    <Child
      name="Third Item"
      handleClick={() => handleClick("Third Item is Clicked!")}
    />
  </div>
);

export default Parent;
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-template-lykqm)

Answer (score 5):

You are calling the `handleClick()` function instead of passing a function to the Child components. Use an inline arrow function to wrap the call.

**Note:** since the arrow functions will be recreated whenever parent is rendered, this might cause a performance issue, if you've got many items, or your render the parent constantly for other reasons.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(null);
  const handleClick = name => {
    setClick(name);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent handleClick={handleClick} />
      {click && <p>{click} is clicked.</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = ({ handleClick }) => (
  <div>
    <Child
      name="First Item"
      handleClick={() => handleClick("First Item is Clicked!")}
    />
    <Child
      name="Second Item"
      handleClick={() => handleClick("Second Item is Clicked!")}
    />
    <Child
      name="Third Item"
      handleClick={() => handleClick("Third Item is Clicked!")}
    />
  </div>
);

const Child = ({ name, handleClick }) => <li onClick={handleClick}>{name}</li>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Another solution is to pass both functions, and text to the Child component, and let it handle the function call. In this case you can memoize the function with `useCallback`:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(null);
  const handleClick = name => {
    setClick(name);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent handleClick={handleClick} />
      {click && <p>{click} is clicked.</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = ({ handleClick }) => (
  <div>
    <Child
      name="First Item"
      handleClick={handleClick} text="First Item is Clicked!"
    />
    <Child
      name="Second Item"
      handleClick={handleClick} text="Second Item is Clicked!"
    />
    <Child
      name="Third Item"
      handleClick={handleClick} text="Third Item is Clicked!"
    />
  </div>
);

const Child = ({ name, handleClick, text }) => {
  const handler = useCallback(() => handleClick(text), [handleClick, text]);
  
  return <li onClick={handler}>{name}</li>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```